# asp.net mvc3 return multiple json list

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Im asp.net mvc3 c# code returns json list like this:

```
return Json(new { name = UserNames, imageUrl = ImageUrls });
```

`UserNames` and `ImageUrls` are both `List<string>` types

And this is my javascript

```
function StartSearch(text) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Shared/Search',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { SearchText: text },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                alert(result[i].name);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

How I can get names and `ImageUrls`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This alerts the value of `Name` from each record of each list.

```
$.each(result, function (i, item) {
    for (var x = 0; x < result.FirstList.length; x++) {
        alert(result.FirstList[x].Name);
        alert(result.SecondList[x].Name);
    }
});
```

This assumes your Json response if formed correctly. Like this:

```
return Json(new { FirstList = results, SecondList = otherResults }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

---

But as a side note, I see other problems with your code that you need to address

1. You're actually not performing a `POST`, you're searching based on input. Change `POST` to `GET` in your Ajax call
2. Change your action return line to allow for the get and make sure your are returning a `JsonResult`.
3. Naming conventions for C# method parameters call for Pascal-casing. Use a lowercase letter for first character

   ```
   public JsonResult Search(string searchText) {
       ....
       return Json(new { name = UserNames, imageUrl = ImageUrls }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you really need to do that inside $.each? couldnt the "for" statement be directly inside the success? Agree with changing POST to GET.

Comment: In the  `.each` method, `i` is each list object so calling `.each` on `result` only iterates over the result, so the first object is the first list, the next object is the next list. So to iterate over the items in each list, a second loop is required. For example, in my test, `.each(result, function(i, item( { alert[i]; }` gives the name of each list, in my case `FirstList` and `SecondList`.

Comment: in your case, you're not doing anything with i or item, so you could remove the $each, and just iterate using the "for", my first response passed in result.name - name is an array, so $.each(result.name,... alert(item); should work

Comment: Yes yours works in that it iterates over the Name list, but then it bypasses the `imageUrl` list. So I guess it's just semantics, either you call `.each` on `result.name` and then a second call after that to `.each` on `result.imageUrl` or you call `.each` on `result` and then an innerloop on the items of each list

Comment: Well it's Json so technically its a dictionary list, it's a list of results because the OP is returning 2 things, a name list, and a Url list. So like I said, in my test, `.each` on just result gives the name of each returned object, name and imageUrls. So to iterate over each list you call `.each` on `result.name` and then a second call on `result.imageUrls`. I can update the GitHub project that I'm testing with if you'd like to check it out

Answer (score 5):

Access name as a property of result like this `result.name[i]`

Essentially, result will contain name and imageUrl which are both arrays, just like you have defined in your anonymous type, so your code should be modified like this to display an alert for each name in the name array

```
function StartSearch(text) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Shared/Search',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { SearchText: text },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result.name, function (i, item) {
                alert(item);
           });
        }
    });
}
```

as `$each` iterates over the items in the name array, it will pass the item to the second parameter of your call back, i.e. item.

so

```
$.each(result.name, function (i, item) {
    alert(item);
});
```

will popup each name.

Notes:

You may want to change the properties on your anonymous type to reflect that they are a collection:

```
return Json(new { UserNames = UserNames, ImageUrls = ImageUrls });
```

this way it will make more sense when you iterate over them in your success function.

As AlfalfaStrange pointed out, I didn't demonstrate how you might access both arrays. Which made me think, what is the relationship between user names and image urls?

Is this a list of images for a user? Maybe what you should consider is creating a specific model for this. For instance, UserDisplayModel:

```
public class UserDisplayModel
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public string ImageUrl {get;set;}
}
```

In your controller return a list of UserDisplayModels. If this is the case, you'll have to rethink why they are two separate lists in the first place. Maybe ImageUrl should be a field on the User table.

So now, when you're returning a single list, e.g.

```
List<UserDisplayModel> users = //get users from db
return Json(new { Users = Users});
```

you can iterate them in one go in js code:

```
       $.each(result.Users, function (i, item) {
            alert(item.Name);
            alert(item.ImageUrl);
        });
```

Comment: kudos for the anticipation of a refinement the OP. well played.