# Javascript variable with function call to .cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a asp.net MVC project and in one of the .cshtml files I have a jquery spinner. When button is clicked it gets the value of the spinner. I wish to take the spinner value and call function (C#) within the .cshtml file and pass variable to the function.

Here is my jquery code within the cshtml. I am trying to implement an ajax POST method to call the function "GetData" with the interval value where the function resides within Index.cshtml (the file with which this code resides)

```
        $('#getvalue').on('click', function (event) {
            var interval = spinner.spinner("value");
            // Make the ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "Index")",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: interval,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('It worked!');
                },
                error: function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);
                }
            });
        });
```

The function GetData is like this, and because it is within cshtml then it is defined as a @Helper function

```
       @helper GetData(int interval)
       {
           var xdata = Model.Select(model => model.Id).Take(10).ToList();
       }
```

The ajax call is throwing an exception (Exception [object Object]). My main suspects for this not working are 1) my "data" format and 2) the "url" being correct.

I am not restricted to only considering ajax, I am open to any method which can call a function and pass variables from Javascript/Jquery to @Helper functions within .cshtml (if indeed this is the best method), maybe I should be using the .cs files more i.e. controllers?

Any help and direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which works is suggested on this post - [asp.net mvc3 return multiple json list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869593/asp-net-mvc3-return-multiple-json-list)

I have moved my GetData function out of cshtml and placed it in a controller.cs

```
    [HttpPost] // can be HttpGet
    public ActionResult GetData(int interval)
    {
        //use interval value here ...

        return Json(new { XList = strxdata, YList = strydata }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I called the GetData function from the cshtml using an AJAX request and then processed the returned data in the same JS code.

```
     $.ajax({
            url: '/SController/GetData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: interval }),
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                    alert(result.XList);
                    alert(result.YList);
                });
                //process the returned data here ....
                var jxArray = result.XList.split(',');
                var jyArray = result.YList.split(',');
                }
        });
```

I hope this helps someone else and in fact I believe it to be technically more correct to split the code out to a controller than to use a @helper function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function within the view, why using ajax? AJAX is used to send data to the server.Here, you only need to call the helper function in click event.

Just do like this.

```
 $('#getvalue').on('click', function (event) {
      var interval = spinner.spinner("value");
      var result = @GetData(interval);
      if(result!=null || result!= 'undefined') {
         alert('It worked!');
      }
 }
```

Comment: When I have tested this solution the error I encounter is that the "interval" within the GetData prototype is "out of context".

Comment: Why are you passing interval to GetData helper? Its not even using that variable.